# Cannot access shared property 'Server' in non shared context

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am running a VB Function to return a true or false value and am getting the error as per the title when running this code.

```
Public shared function  DoesFileExist(fileName As String) As boolean
    return File.Exists(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("..", "docStore", fileName)))
End function
```

Can anyone shed some light on how I would get around \ resolve this issue please.

It is being called from another shared function which is decalred like this

```
Private Shared Function BuildHtmlTable(ByVal dataTable As DataTable, excludeInspectionColumn As Boolean) As StringBuilder
...
End Function
```

however, there are other shared functions that also called during `BuildHtmlTable(..)`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`